# Drive API - Parse Error when inserting file

Tags: python, google-drive-api, python-requests

I need to create a new file in a Google Drive with `requests` python library.

```
r = requests.post(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files',
    headers={
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token
    }
)
```

This code can succesfully create a file with all values set to default, but if I try to e.g. set a title of the file:

```
r = requests.post(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files',
    data={"title": "Foo"},
    headers={
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % self.access_token
    }
)
```

Then the server responds with `400 Bad Request` and json response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400, 
    "message": "Parse Error", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Parse Error", 
        "reason": "parseError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that, when a json request is sent, then data argument should be a serialized json object.

```
r = requests.post(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files',
    data=json.dumps({"title": "Foo"}),
    headers={
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % self.access_token
    }
)
```